# NewliquidCrystal example HelloWorld_i2c just flickers

Tags: lcd

I've bought a cheap I2C LCD display (specs in the end of this question).

I can't make it print. I've tested with two displays of same model, so nothing is broken.

I am using the NewliquidCrystal 1.3.4 library, ie not the "normal" LiquidCrystal library. I'm trying with the I2C example called HelloWorld_i2c ([link to example code](https://bitbucket.org/fmalpartida/new-liquidcrystal/raw/20245cfb111aadad288f73102fcf353356a89651/examples/HelloWorld_i2c/HelloWorld_i2c.pde)). I've only changed the address from 0x37 to 0x27.

It compiles fine, but the result is only that the display flickers.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

### Super simple example flickers too

Well, this one gives just one blink.

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27);  // Set the LCD I2C address
void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);               // initialize the lcd 
  lcd.home ();                   // go home
  lcd.print("Hello, ARDUINO ");  
}
void loop()
{
}
```

### Pictures

In the light it shows that the writing to the display is randomly jumping around.

[image]

In the dark, it shows that the background light flickers:

[image]

### Details about the LCD display

Text on the backside

```
YwRobot Arduino
QAPASS
LCM1602 IIC V1
```

Text on the chip

```
TLPCF85747
HA
T62281
A N 1
I L knM988223
```

Comment: First hit on google: https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/LCD-Blue-I2C - have you followed all that first?

Comment: This is probably an issue of wiring; include your schematic.

Comment: @Majenko: in fact I did look at that example before posting. I thought that did not work either; though in a different way; it just did not show anything. In fact the Arduino-Info example *did* work! But the display contrast setting was bad, my room is very bright, and most important: I was looking at it at a bad angle; and therefore I could not see any text. So if the contrast would have been set right, I would have had luck with the Arduino-Info example.

Comment: Regarding the HelloWorld_I2C example; by using this constructor call it worked: `LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);`

Comment: @Majenko: If you like, you can post an answer; to use this other constructor.

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself since it was you that worked out how to get it working. I merely showed you the path :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make the example run as intended, by using a different constructor call:

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);
```

I am not able to tell you, what these parameters and values mean. However, the documentation for this constructor is shown below ([source](https://github.com/marcmerlin/NewLiquidCrystal/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h#L100)).

```
/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Class constructor. 
    @discussion Initializes class variables and defines the I2C address of the
    LCD. The constructor does not initialize the LCD.

    @param      lcd_Addr[in] I2C address of the IO expansion module. For I2CLCDextraIO,
    the address can be configured using the on board jumpers.
    @param      En[in] LCD En (Enable) pin connected to the IO extender module
    @param      Rw[in] LCD Rw (Read/write) pin connected to the IO extender module
    @param      Rs[in] LCD Rs (Reset) pin connected to the IO extender module
    @param      d0[in] LCD data 0 pin map on IO extender module
    @param      d1[in] LCD data 1 pin map on IO extender module
    @param      d2[in] LCD data 2 pin map on IO extender module
    @param      d3[in] LCD data 3 pin map on IO extender module
    */
   LiquidCrystal_I2C( uint8_t lcd_Addr, uint8_t En, uint8_t Rw, uint8_t Rs, 
                     uint8_t d0, uint8_t d1, uint8_t d2, uint8_t d3 )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull the I2C sensor at the back of the LCD board, you can see that it is shorted to the SMD mounted on the back,  just pull it a little so that it won't touch and short the conductors. This has happened to me, try it if this works.